# Content Deployment - Resuming from a messed up deployment

Tags: content-deployment

We have an incremental CD running, say from stage to production, and for some reason yesterday the export worked and import failed. We fixed the offending issue in the target/prod server, next time when we restart the content deployment, the source Central Admin doesn't seem to export the objects that were previously successfully exported. Is there a way to "force" to export the content from a particular day?

Answer (score 2):

Create a job that only runs on demand that will export everything, no matter when it was published previously. Run this manually. It will be good to have it in case this should happen again.

Comment: Yeah I have that already as a powershell and also can do full content deployment. I can do it by lists/files names etc using powershell or content deployment wizard. But I was looking for some shortcut to export only selectively by date. As a side note, where does SharePoint store the info on what was previously exported?